# Firestore crashing app with new dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Yesterday I updated the dependencies of Firestore with `17.1.1` and Google Services with `4.1.0`. Now while launching the app it crashes.

**Note:**

If I change Google Services to `4.0.2`, the Firestore initializes properly and the app works as expected.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

---

**Update:**

Changing to `4.2.0` works.

---

**Logs:**

```
Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
... I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{\...\/\...\.ui.MessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process \...\. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process \...\. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:240)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:68)
        at \...\.ServiceLocator.provideFirestore(ServiceLocator.java:18)
        at \...\.ServiceLocator.provideMessageRepository(ServiceLocator.java:28)
        at \...\.ServiceLocator.provideMessageViewModelFactory(ServiceLocator.java:33)
        at \...\.ui.MessageActivity.onCreate(MessageActivity.java:112)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**gradle Project:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**gradle app:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    // ...
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    // ...
    // Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    // Crash Reports
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Do you initalize Firebase correctly, with calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)`, before working with Firebase entities?

Comment: But Firestore initializes the component by `FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize

Comment: But before you call `FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` you need to initalize Firebase with `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)`. Usually this is done in your `Application` class.

Comment: I already tried that, it did not helped. `app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)`; `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(app);`

Comment: There is no need to use `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)`. Using only the dependencies is enough. Have you tried to use: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` instead of `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'`. Does it work? Please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo changing the gradle version worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)`. Using only the dependencies is enough. So you shouldn't ever have to call it manually if you performed the standard integration, as it will be invoked automatically a startup via a `ContentProvider` that will initialize before any other Activity or Service.  You can read Doug's post regarding on [how to initialize Firebase on Android](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html).

The problem in your code is that your are using for your project the `alpha13` version for your gradle. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

Will solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is a confirmed bug in the play-services plugin 4.1.0 according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112716914. The answer is to use an earlier version, e.g. 4.0.2.

Edit: Version 4.2.0 is released where the bug is fixed.

Comment: Or use use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

Comment: `4.2.0` is released, and it's not crashing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Switching  to 4.2.0 Solves the issue.