# Firestore: Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Updating Firestore core from `16.0.4` to `16.0.5` is giving me the error:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb
```

Update for another error:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz
```

---

**Update:**

[Firebase release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) doesn't shows anything about Firestore core `16.0.5` till date, but in Android Studio it's linting for update. So reverted it back to `16.0.4` until there is an official update.

---

**Update** 14/11

While compiling now it shows these errors:

```
com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdx: can't find referenced method 'boolean zzfy()' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz

com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb: can't find referenced method 'void transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(int,android.os.Parcel)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzq

com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzee: can't find referenced method 'void transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(int,android.os.Parcel)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzq

com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeh: can't find referenced method 'void transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(int,android.os.Parcel)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzq

com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzez: can't find referenced method 'zzea(android.os.Looper)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea

com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfu: can't find referenced method 'void zzb(android.os.Bundle)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzef

com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw: can't find referenced method 'zzea(android.os.Looper)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea

there were 7 unresolved references to program class members.

Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0'
    // Paging
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.0.0'
    // Android Room
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // Jsoup
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    // Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5' //.4
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    // .4
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.1'
    // Crash Reports
//    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-beta04'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}
```

More

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\72.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\73.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\86.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\87.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\88.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\89.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\90.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\91.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\92.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\93.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\94.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\95.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\96.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\97.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\98.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\99.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\100.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\101.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\102.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\103.jar
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\72.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\73.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\86.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\87.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\88.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\89.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\90.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\91.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\92.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\93.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\94.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\95.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\96.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\97.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\98.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\99.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\100.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\101.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\102.jar, C:\Users\\...\\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\103.jar
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:122)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: Make sure the rest of your dependencies are updated as well.

Comment: Everything updated

Comment: Try to Run `gradle app:dependencies` to find conflicting:dependency, look for package `com.google.android.gms.internal`. Follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree) to dig .

Comment: Didn't find any `com.google.android.gms.internal` but found many with `.measurement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After *several tries* within Android Studio it got fixed.

Definition of "several tries":

- Sync Project with Gradle files
- Re-import Gradle project
- Sync with file system
- Invalidate caches / restart
- and repeat once again :(

Now which one did actually worked I don't know, but for you `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6` is released and it works exceptionally well for an update.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.1'
```

And make sure to have also the latest version of Google Play services:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Please also add the following dependecy:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

Comment: Is already on `google-services:4.2.0`, updating the `ui-auth` dependency did not work.

Comment: Hi Rajarshi! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: No, however, I've updated the post with latest errors

Comment: Using the code above, do you still get the initial error?

Comment: yes, also see the second update, firestore core 16.0.5 is not released yet.

Comment: Have you tried to change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-beta04'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1''`. Furthermore, according to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5` is released on `October 16, 2018`, right?

Comment: I think you are mistaken. I'm talking about firestore core `16.0.5` that is `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5`

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. What is happening when you are using `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4` along with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`, does it work?

Comment: with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-beta04'`, `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4` it builds successfully.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) and I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google play services can be updated to com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

Try that and check if it works :)

Comment: No, it didn't worked. By the way, when did it got released, previously `4.1.0` was crashing the app. More at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658537/firestore-crashing-app-with-new-dependencies