# FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running Firebase Firestore in my app.
And I get Null Pointer Exception right on calling first two lines:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
```

From build.gradle - Project:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' (also tried 4.0.0)
```

From build.gradle - App: (latest at the moment)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3'
```

If I set breakpoint on creating instance - I end up at ActivityThread class - registerOnActivityPausedListener method. 
http://take.ms/Fdh7z

Code is definitely fine as it's working on other devices. But on one of them (Wileyfox Swift 2) I get NLP and no good explanation:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzab.zzf(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.addIdTokenListener(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:76)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.newInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:109)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreMultiDbComponent.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:51)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:87)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:72)
        at com.myjob.exchange.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6723)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
```

Comment: Have you tried to instantiate the db object without `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)`? What is the behaviour? Have you also tried to use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` instead of `4.1.0`?

Comment: After reinstalling app on my other device - I started getting same problems.
As for instantiating without FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) or version of google services - doesn't change a thing

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658537/firestore-crashing-app-with-new-dependencies), there is no need to use `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)`. Google services are mandatory. And I strongly recommend you to use the latest version of `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`.

Comment: Removed FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context), put 4.2.0, error remains.

Comment: Are you using authentication? If yes, please share the content of your both build.gradle files.

Comment: Yes, I'm using authentication.
These changes made the magic. I've rolled back core and firestore.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have connected your app with Firebase (google-services.json) file, then try this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Crash on the first line

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in these lines:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3'
```

After changing to these things got back to work:

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3' implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Class

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

TO

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```